# Make excel export every row in multiple XML files

Tags: xml, excel

I have a project I'm working on where I need to convert every excel row to an XML file. I have more than 10K rows and it would really hard to them all manually. I have been looking around for a mean to automate this task but I could not find any. Is it even possible for excel to do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to automate this process using VBA (commonly referred to as "macros"). Look into Loops, writing to text files, and exporting to XML.

The following links should get you started:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6950/Export-Excel-to-XML-in-VBA
- http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm
- http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-looping-through-a-range-of-cells/
- http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/write-data-to-text-file.html